# Internet Explorer no acepta la propiedad forEach

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código que se ejecuta en Firefox y en chrome pero cuando se lo voy a ejecutar en IE me da error:

```
El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'forEach'
```

Me vi algunas búsquedas y encontré

https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/01/06/object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach/

Mi idea entonces era cambiar los:

```
   return b += '<ul class="slide">', this.props.collectionData.forEach(function(c) {
                            b += '<li class="carouselItem">', b += a.contentItem1(c), b += '</li>'
                        }), b += '</ul>', b}

...... )), d.forEach(function(b) {
```

Por los

```
this.props.collectionData.prototype.forEach
```

Simplemente añadiendo prototype antes del.forEach y obtengo el error de:
SCRIPT5007: No se puede obtener la propiedad 'forEach' de referencia nula o sin definir

El código JS no es mío y no sabría tampoco como meterle mano con for() normales porque están dentro de returns...

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de IE estás utilizando? `forEach` está totalmente soportado a partir de IE10 y parcialmente en IE9 (https://caniuse.com/#search=foreach). ¿Estás seguro de que `this.props.colectionData` tiene valor?

Comment: uso la IE-11, tiene datos, es un [Object NodeList] con length = 1, Sino tuviera datos, no funcionaría con Chrome o con firefox,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que [IE (cualquier versión)  no implementa el método `forEach` en la clase `NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility).

Cuando haces algo como

```js
let elems=document.querySelectorAll('span');
console.log(elems instanceof Array);
console.log(elems instanceof NodeList);
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <span>Hola</span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>todos</span>
  <span>!</span>
</div>
```

Obtienes una NodeList, no un Array de elementos.

Lo que puedes hacer es *robar* el método de Array:

```js
//Quitamos a NodeList el método, para simular IE
NodeList.prototype.forEach = undefined;


let elems = document.querySelectorAll('span');
console.log(elems instanceof Array);
console.log(elems instanceof NodeList);
try {
  elems.forEach(e => console.log(e));
} catch (error) {
  console.log('Error:', error.message)
}

//tomamos prestado el método de la clase Array
NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

elems.forEach(e => console.log(e));
```

```html
<div id="contenedor">
  <span>Hola</span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>todos</span>
  <span>!</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Por lo que leo [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) el `forEach` para un `NodeList` no está soportado en IE.

En [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach) pregunta de SO lo explican mejor.

Además proponen varias soluciones:

1. Utilizando una llamada al método [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/call):

```js
var myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll("p");
[].forEach.call(myNodelist, function(item, index, array) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript HTML DOM!</h2>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<p>Hello Norway!</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

2. Creando un `array` a partir de tu `nodeList`:

```js
let myNodelist = document.querySelectorAll("p");
let nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(myNodelist,0); 

nodes.forEach(function(node){ 
    console.log(node);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>JavaScript HTML DOM!</h2>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<p>Hello Norway!</p>

<p id="demo"></p>
```